# Max/Min comparing two values in Spark withColumn and not aggregate

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aggregate-functions

In a column calculation, I have an operation like this

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.withColumn("col_cal", .../(F.exp(col("col_A")))
```

`F.exp(col("col_A"))` may be too small and explode the calculated value at col_cal. I would like to limit it when it approach 0. In other words, if it's too small, replace by epsilon

```
epsilon = 0.001
df = df.withColumn("col_cal", .../F.max((F.exp(col("col_A"))), epsilon)
```

However F.max is an aggregated function and not accepted here.
How could I use normal max/min comparison in spark data frame calculation like this ?

Comment: Use [`least`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.least) and [`greatest`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.greatest) for `min` and `max` of a list of columns, respectively.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to calculate max value in some columns per row in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44833836/how-to-calculate-max-value-in-some-columns-per-row-in-pyspark) or [PySpark: compute row maximum of the subset of columns and add to an exisiting dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40874657/pyspark-compute-row-maximum-of-the-subset-of-columns-and-add-to-an-exisiting-da)

Comment: so in your case: `df = df.withColumn("col_cal", .../F.greatest((F.exp(col("col_A"))), F.lit(epsilon))`

Comment: Thanks @pault . Is this the most efficient way to achieve what I wanted, or a F.when.((F.exp(col("col_A")) < epsilon, epsilon).otherwise(.../(F.exp(col("col_A"))) is better? In my thought, this require double calculation of (F.exp(col("col_A")), therefore I went with greatest of the two.

Comment: Most likely it won't make a difference in efficiency in your case. The difference, if any, will be negligible. Do whatever is easier for you, code wise. I also suggest accepting one of the dupes I linked and closing this question.