# Function to select max per row

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset of videogames that includes all their sales per region (NA, EU, JP, Other) in each column.

| Game | NA_Sales | EU sales | JP Sales | Other Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Wii Sports | 10 | 5 | 8 | 2 |
| Mario Kart | 5 | 3 | 8 | 1 |

I want to create a function that will iterate each row and return the max value for each game. So when I run the UDF function to create a new column, it will return me 10 for Wii Sports and 8 for Mario Kart.

Any comment or help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Use [`greatest`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.greatest.html) function: `df.select(col("Game"), greatest(col("NA"), col("EU"), col("JP"), col("Other")).alias("max"))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to calculate max value in some columns per row in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44833836/how-to-calculate-max-value-in-some-columns-per-row-in-pyspark)

Comment: @WinterSoldier it's a dataframe.

Comment: @blackbishop Yeah that made the job actually. Is there any way of doing it with a function though? Because I want to return the name of the column, not the number. Sorry for not being clear before.

Comment: Then see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56389696/select-column-name-per-row-for-max-value-in-pyspark) post

Comment: @blackbishop that was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For a `UDF` free solution, you can find the maximum sales across columns using [`greatest`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.greatest.html?highlight=greatest) and then apply [`when`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.when.html?highlight=when#pyspark.sql.functions.when) to find the column containing this value.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Column
from typing import List

data = [("Wii Sports", 10, 5, 8, 2,),
        ("Mario Kart", 5, 3, 8, 1,), ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("Game", "NA_Sales", "EU sales", "JP Sales", "Other Sales",))

def find_region_max_sales(cols: List[str]) -> Column:
    max_sales = F.greatest(*[F.col(c) for c in cols])
    max_col_expr = F
    for c in cols:
        max_col_expr = max_col_expr.when(F.col(c) == max_sales, c)
    return max_col_expr

df.withColumn("region_with_maximum_sales", find_region_max_sales(metric_cols)).show()

"""
+----------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+-------------------------+
|      Game|NA_Sales|EU sales|JP Sales|Other Sales|region_with_maximum_sales|
+----------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+-------------------------+
|Wii Sports|      10|       5|       8|          2|                 NA_Sales|
|Mario Kart|       5|       3|       8|          1|                 JP Sales|
+----------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+-------------------------+
"""
```